# sharepoint placeholder bottom not refreshing

Tags: sharepoint, placeholder, spfx

I've created a bottom placeholder with spfx and react and it contains a menu. when I select an option from the dropdown menu the page refresh but the bottom placeholder still showing the dropdown oppened, i like everything refreshes but not the bottom placeholder. 
Does the placeholder a refresh when a new page loads?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on page load all the elements in the page will be reloaded. In OnInit method, call the render placeholders method like this.

```
this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

Comment: Great! Please mark it as answer, so that helps for others who face the similar issue.